# How to repeatedly spawn blocks behind each players?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

What me and my friends want to do is make a slight copy of tron but niether of us know how to spawn blocks about a block away for each player. How do we do this and what kind of command block do we need? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use the relative coordinates and detect orientation selectors for that.

First we need to work with the relative coordinates combined with execute command, so we can detect for orientation of the player later:

North:

```
/execute @a[rym=135,ry=-135] ~ ~ ~ setblock ~ ~ ~1 stained_glass 11
```

South:

```
/execute @a[ry=22,rym=-22] ~ ~ ~ setblock ~ ~ ~-1 stained_glass 11
```

East

```
/execute @a[rym=-135,ry=-45] ~ ~ ~ setblock ~-1 ~ ~ stained_glass 11
```

West

```
/execute @a[rym=-135,ry=-45] ~ ~ ~ setblock ~1 ~ ~ stained_glass 11
```

This commands sets a block of stained glass behind the player for each direction.

You have to run all these commands on a clock to set permanently blocks behind the player, depending of his orientation.

Comment: Huh. I was going to answer this with the same commands :P but you answered first

Comment: I'm sorry :D Hope you will find an empty question =]

Comment: Will this work if I walk backward ?

Comment: If you continue to look in south and wal backwards for example it will spawn glass forwards you